# How to rollback just one step using rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dbmigrate

After adding migration files in the `db/migrate` folder and running `rake db:migrate`, I want get back to the previous step, I think using `VERSION=n` is the right way to do that, but I don't know the correct value of n to use. Is there any command to check the current n value?

It would be great if anyone could provide full instructions on how to use `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 418, accepted):

For starters

`rake db:rollback` will get you back one step

then

`rake db:rollback STEP=n`

Will roll you back `n` migrations where `n` is the number of recent migrations you want to rollback.

More references [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Migrations).

Answer (score 117):

Roll back the most recent migration:

```
rake db:rollback
```

Roll back the `n` most recent migrations:

```
rake db:rollback STEP=n
```

You can find full instructions on the use of Rails migration tasks for rake on the [Rails Guide for running migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-migrations).

---

Here's some more:

- `rake db:migrate` - Run all migrations that haven't been run already
- `rake db:migrate VERSION=20080906120000` - Run all necessary migrations (up or down) to get to the given version
- `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` - Run migrations in the given environment
- `rake db:migrate:redo` - Roll back one migration and run it again
- `rake db:migrate:redo STEP=n` - Roll back the last `n` migrations and run them again
- `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20080906120000` - Run the `up` method for the given migration
- `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20080906120000` - Run the `down` method for the given migration

---

And to answer your question about where you get a migration's version number from:

> The version is the numerical prefix on the migration's filename. For
>   example, to migrate to version 20080906120000 run
>
> ```
> $ rake db:migrate VERSION=20080906120000
> ```

(From [Running Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-migrations) in the Rails Guides)

Comment: When rake db:rollback wasn't working to rollback the most recent migration, I had to use rake db:migrate VERSION=<second last version date> and it worked fine

Answer (score 8):

Best way is running Particular migration again by using down or up(in rails 4. It's change)

> rails db:migrate:up VERSION=timestamp

Now how you get the timestamp.
Go to this path

> /db/migrate

Identify migration file you want to revert.pick the timestamp from that file name.

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question, it is indeed the best way. Rolling back by steps can cause mistakes, especially when working on software in a group.

Answer (score 6):

If the version is `20150616132425`, then use:

```
rails db:migrate:down VERSION=20150616132425
```

Answer (score 3):

Other people have already answered you how to rollback, but you also asked how you could identify the version number of a migration.

- `rake db:migrate:status` gives a list of your migrations version, name and status (up or down)
- Your can also find the migration file, which contain a timestamp in the filename, that is the version number. Migrations are located in folder: `/db/migrate`

Comment: By the way if you run the status command, you might see lines like:
********** NO FILE **********
Those migrations is not existing on your current branch if you use git.

Answer (score -3):

```
  try {
        $result=DB::table('users')->whereExists(function ($Query){
            $Query->where('id','<','14162756');
            $Query->whereBetween('password',[14162756,48384486]);
            $Query->whereIn('id',[3,8,12]);
        });
    }catch (\Exception $error){
        Log::error($error);
        DB::rollBack(1);
        return redirect()->route('bye');
    }
```

Comment: This question already contains multiple answers and an accepted answer. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answers? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.