# How to undo the action of rails db:migrate in Rails 5.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

When migrating the database, I made a spelling mistake.

I want to generate a scaffold by running:

```
rails generate scaffold Micropost context:text user_id:integer
rails db:migrate
```

Although I made a mistake by leaving out the colon when I ran:

```
rails generate scaffold Micropost context:text user_id integer
rails db:migrate
```

I want to undo this migration, how to do it?
(I'm using Rails `5.0.0.1`)

When I run `rails db:migrate`, I get an error of:

```
 SQLite3::SQLException: table "microposts" already exists:
```

When I run `rails db:migrate:status`, I get the following output:

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name  
 up       20161024021157  Create users  
 up       20161024025545  ********** NO FILE **********  
 down     20161024025805  Create microposts
```

I tried to use `rails db:migrate:down VERSION=20161024025805`. There wasn't any message showing in the command line. Then I ran `rails db:migrate`. The error is the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rollback just one step using rake db:migrate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352848/how-to-rollback-just-one-step-using-rake-dbmigrate)

Comment: I'm using Rails 5.0.0.1, not the former versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rails db:rollback` will simply rollback *one* [migration](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Migrations#Managing_Migrations) which I believe is what you are looking for

For a more specific rollback, you can run `rails db:migrate:down VERSION=numberofversion`

Replace the `numberofversion` with the version number of the migration file generated, for example:

```
rails db:migrate:down VERSION=1843652238
```

**Edit:**

Since you are getting the error that the `Microposts` table already exists, you must follow these steps to remove the table:

1. Run `rails generate migration DropMicroposts`
2. Go to the `/db/migrate folder` and find the latest migration file you just created
3. In that file paste this:

   ```
   class DropMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration 
     def up 
       drop_table :microposts 
     end 
   end
   ```
4. run `rails db:migrate`
5. After this, run `rails generate scaffold Micropost context:text user_id:integer`
6. Then run `rails db:migrate`

Comment: The message of running `rails db:migrate:down VERSION=1843652238` tells me to use db:rollback. But running db:rollback shows nothing. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you actually replace the version number with the version number of the migration you created?

Comment: Is Migration ID the version number ?

Comment: In the db/migrate folder, you have files like 241294283_add_something_to_something . The version number is the number at the front of the file that you want to rollback

Comment: After doing `rails db:migrate:down VERSION=20161024025805`, it still says `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table "microposts" already exists`

Comment: After running `rails db:migrate:down VERSION=20161024025805`, then I run `rails db:migrate`, it still says `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table "microposts" already exists`

Comment: I think you need to read more on rails migrations. After rolling back a migration, you need to delete the migration file, then create a new migration that is *correct* and **then** run `rails db:migrate`. If you just rollback then migrate again, nothing has changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126488/discussion-between-niaomingjian-and-luka-kerr).